# MAC OS X: Installed MySQL, Cannot locate MySQLCOM/ directory under /Library/StartupItems/ directory

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm working on Mac OS X Yosemite (version: 10.10.5) and I want to use MySQL as database for my web app.

I downloaded MySQL -- "mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64.dmg", and successfully installed it.

I'm following the steps given in:
http://geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/installation/how_to_download_and_install_mysql_on_mac_os_x.php

Where I'm at this step --

```
    **"Install and setup auto start package for MySQL on OS X":**
    you should now be able to start MySQL running the following command in OS X Terminal window 

    $ sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

However I'm unable to locate MySQLCOM directory under /Library/StartupItems/ directory

```
    [Terminal]:$ pwd
    /Library/StartupItems

    [Terminal]:$ ls -l
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  170 Dec  7 22:55 HWNetMgr
    drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  204 Dec  7 22:55 HWPortDetect
    drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  340 Dec  7 22:55 StartOuc
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 Sep 30 14:12 cma
```